# Whats wrong with this express code?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Hello i am trying to check two mysql values and if its matching anything in the database it needs to generate a token but it does not seem to work :(
Everytime i run this code i get a connection time out:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require("mysql");
var randomstring = require("randomstring");
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // First you need to create a connection to the db
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "segfault",
  password: "wnk9ctte2endcKzBKtre7auE",
  database: "segfault"
});
connection.connect();
var input_user = req.body.username;
var input_pass = req.body.password;
var token = randomstring.generate(12);
connection.query('SELECT username FROM segfault.users AS username', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  for(var i in rows){
    username = rows[i].username;
    if(input_user == username){
      connection.query('SELECT password FROM segfault.users AS password', function(err, rows, fields) {
          if(rows[i].password == input_pass){
              res.send("OK: "+ token);
              console.log("OK:" + token)
          }
      });

    }
  }

});
connection.end();

});

module.exports = router;
```

tell me please what i am dooing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You close the connection to the database without waiting for the result of the query.

Move `connection.end();` inside callback after the `res.send`.